# E: Unable to locate package linux-tools-5.4.0-77-generic on WSL Debian 11

Tags: usb, debian, apt, packages, wsl2

I'm following this oficial guide to **[Connecting USB devices to WSL2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/connecting-usb-devices-to-wsl/)** but I'm stuck installing ***linux-tools-5.4.0-77-generic***. I'm executing the `$ sudo apt install linux-tools-5.4.0-77-generic` command but it gaves me the next error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-tools-5.4.0-77-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-tools-5.4.0-77-generic'
```

I've tried:

1. $ sudo apt upgrade.
2. $ sudo apt update.
3. Editing /etc/apt/sources.list
   manually.
4. Download the binary files from [https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-updates-main-amd64/linux-tools-5.4.0-77-generic_5.4.0-77.86~18.04.1_amd64.deb.html](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-updates-main-amd64/linux-tools-5.4.0-77-generic_5.4.0-77.86%7E18.04.1_amd64.deb.html) and installing manually with $ sudo apt install ./path/to/binary.file.deb.

Please follow the next github issue to get more details about my WSL environment.

[Issue on WSL](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/7652).

Thanks in advance, I'm still learning about WSL.

Comment: Ubuntu is based on Debian but they are very different. NEVER use packages from one on the other. The guide you followed is for Ubuntu.

Comment: That's what I suspect, but where can I find for similar packages? Is that means I can't proceed with the guide because there isn't a similar package for Debian?

Comment: I haven't tried it on Debian, but a quick search [says](https://packages.debian.org/buster/usbip) that the usbip tools (which are in `linux-tools` on Ubuntu) are in the `usbip` package on Debian Buster.  See if that works, and we can add it as an answer if so.

Answer (score 9):

This turns out to be even easier in Debian than in Ubuntu.  Simply:

```
sudo apt install usbip hwdata usbutils
```

There's no need to modify `sudoers` with `visudo` since Debian installs `usbib` to `/usr/sbin` (which is already in the `secure_path`.

Given the above, and assuming Debian is your default WSL instance, then the rest of the instructions (e.g. `usbipd wsl`) should work.

However, at this point, the `usbipd wsl` only seems to work with the default WSL instance.  If Debian is not your default WSL distribution (as noted by `wsl -l -v`), then you just need to set things up in two stages.

First, share/bind the device from Windows (in an Administrator prompt):

```
usbipd list
usbipd bind --busid <bus-id>
```

Then attach to it from inside Debian via:

```
sudo usbip attach -r $HOSTNAME.local -b <bus-id>
```

The `$HOSTNAME.local` uses [mDNS to connect to the Windows host](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69407064/11810933).

`lsusb` should then show the device.