# Access Mobile Device Filesystem from WSL?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to access the filesystem of my Android mobile device in Windows-Subsystem-For-Linux:

[image: mobile-device-filesystem]

I executed the command `mount`, but I only see `/mnt/c` and `/mnt/g`.

Is there a way to get access to file on my mobile device.

Comment: The keyword here is “MTP” ([Media Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol)). It's probably not possible, especially because this isn’t filesystem access in the first place.

Comment: https://www.mtpdrive.com/ might be a paid solution. There is a trial but it is somewhat limited. I've never tried it hence only a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get this working using the new USB/IP feature in WSL, along with `jmtpfs`.

##### USB/IP

See [the official Microsoft docs for WSL2 USB/IP support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/connect-usb).

First, whether you are running Windows 10 or Windows 11, `wsl --update` to the latest kernel (or App Store release with kernel) which has USB/IP support.

After that, however, the exact steps will depend on:

- As with most things, directions for Ubuntu are standard.  See my post on [Debian](https://superuser.com/a/1688086/1210833) for the changes needed for that distro.
- The instructions from Microsoft and the usbipd-win project both assume that you are using your default WSL distribution.  If you have more than one distribution, and need to access it in a non-default one, you can still manually run `usbip` from within WSL2.

##### `jmtpfs`

Once you've shared your phone from Windows to WSL over USB/IP and can see it with `lsusb`, then you should be able to mount it using `jmtpfs`:

```
sudo apt install jmtpfs
sudo mkdir /media/android
sudo jmtpfs -o allow_other /media/android/
```

Refer to the [jmtpfs readme](https://github.com/JasonFerrara/jmtpfs) for more info.

It seems that after unmounting, the USB/IP connection is "lost" or damaged, so I had to `detach` and `attach` the device again on the Windows side before I could try anything else with it.

Comment: I encountered this error:
Libusb1 init failed 
LIBMTP PANIC: get_mtp_usb_device_list() error code: 3 on line 646 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'MtpError' 
  what(): 
Aborted (core dumped)